# I am trying to update a user comment when the user clicks on edit comment, when the user clicks edit the comment is gone

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Here is my code and file structure

In the /comments page when you click on the details link and it goes to the Edit page, then when you click on Edit comment, and it takes you to the edit page you can edit the comment but once you click on save, it goes back to /comment but the edit comment and the original comment is gone.  Not sure what is wrong with my logic in the code?

```
node_modules
views/comments
  edit.ejs
  index.ejs
  new.ejs
  show.ejs
index.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "practicerest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Practice ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Manny Verma",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

edit.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Edit</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/comments/<%=comment.id%>?_method=PATCH">
        <textarea name="listing" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><%= comment.comment %> </textarea>
        <button>Save</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
const { urlencoded } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const { v4: uuid } = require('uuid');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

let comments = [{
        id: uuid(),
        username: 'Todd Barkley',
        comment: 'Alright movie!!!!'
    },
    {
        id: uuid(),
        username: 'David Smith',
        comment: 'Oh my that was a weird movie'
    },
    {
        id: uuid(),
        User: 'Erick Jones',
        comment: 'Terrible movie, I walked out half way through it.'
    }
]

//comments
app.get('/comments', (req, res) => {
    res.render('comments/index', { comments });
})

//new
app.get('/comments/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('comments/new');
})

app.post('/comments', (req, res) => {
    const { username, comment } = req.body;
    comments.push({ username, comment, id: uuid() })
    res.redirect('/comments');
})

//show
app.get('/comments/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const comment = comments.find(l => l.id === id);
    res.render('comments/show', { comment });
})

//Edit
app.get('/comments/:id/edit', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const comment = comments.find(l => l.id === id);
    res.render('comments/edit', { comment });
})

// updating
app.patch('/comments/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const newCommentText = req.body.comment;
    const foundComment = comments.find(l => l.id === id);
    foundComment.comment = newCommentText;
    res.redirect('/comments');
})

//delete
app.delete('/comments/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    comments = comments.filter(l => l.id !== id);
    // filter is a boolean function, for whatever the call back returns true for those elements will be added to the filter array, you want to try to not mutate an array you should make a copy and make a change to the copy of the array that's what comment.filter is doing, it's returning a new array
    res.redirect('/comments');
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("On port 4000")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using app.put() instead of app.patch()

```js
app.put('/comments/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const newCommentText = req.body.comment;
    const foundComment = comments.find(l => l.id === id);
    foundComment.comment = newCommentText;
    res.redirect('/comments');
})
```

Comment: Nope, Still not working, I believe if you have you ?_method=PATCH it changes it to a patch route since as far as I know there is only get and post for express so the method has to be post and then with the ?_method=PATCH it says this is a "patch" I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm certain that express has put functionality. 
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

Comment: However I have never used the method-override So I'm not entirely sure what the purpose of that dependency is. However looking at their documentation I don't see anything about using PATCH as a method through this dependency.